# How to write a Powershell logic to extract particular field from a line containing different characters

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with lines:

```
abc-def-snapshot xxx.yyy/dummypath,
abc-def-snapshot xxx.yyy/dummypath,
.
.
```

Need to extract fields from lines based on char(i.e., ".", "-","/").

I tried running:

```
$a=get-content .\test.txt
$a|where-object {$_ -like ("*.*") -And ("*/*")}
```

This outputs the whole line but not just second field.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Split the line on dot and slash and pick the 2nd element?

Comment: What is the output supposed to be?

Comment: Output supposed to be:  xxx.yyy/dummypath, as per the command i mentioned above

Comment: @vonPryz yeah that way i can.   $a.split("/")[0] -o/p for this will be xxx.yyy. But without using the split is there a way?? like if i run $a|where-object {$_ -like ("*.*") -And ("*/*")} why am i getting whole line abc-def-snapshot xxx.yyy/dummypath and why not just xxx.yyy/dummypath